# Exclude specific frontend URL from https://

Tags: url, url-rewrite, https, base-url, secure

I have a Magento website and have enabled *https://* across the whole site by configuring the unsecure Base URL. The site also uses the following API URL which **CANNOT** be https, but because of the config settings is redirects to https:

http://www.domain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1

Is there a way that I can exclude certain URLs from using secure URLs?

Comment: enable https only for secure pages and than use https for required pages. so that remaining pages will exclude from https.

Answer (score 2):

Extend Magento's controller that forces the redirect to https ([about the controller](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/73982852329/magento-base-url-redirect)). When your module detects this URL instruct Magento to bypass the https redirect.

Comment: If you continue to have problems I'll provide a code example.

Comment: Im having the exact same problem and it's giving me headaches. @AdamMoss We're you able to fix this using iusemagentonow's answer? Could either of you post an code example?

Comment: I've played around in this file but I can't identify how to stop this redirecting. I tried putting this around the rewrite method in the dispatch(0 function: if ($request->getRequestUri() !== "/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1") {
            $this->_getRequestRewriteController()->rewrite();
        } but no luck.